# Python tkinter textvariable doesnt appear on window before the end of the function. (I think) it ignores everything in function except time.sleep

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a very simple timer clock in tkinter. But I have this problem that I can't manage to fix. When I run my code and call my function by pressing the button, nothing appears in the window before the function is finished. It seems like either the textvariable never gets updated, or that it doesn't appear on my screen for some reason. Thanks for any help:)
This is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

root.title("timer")
root.geometry("200x250")

start_text = Label(root, text="Timer test")
start_text.grid(row=1, column=1)

def start():
    timer = 5
    for i in range(5):
        timer.sleep(1)
        timer_text.set(str(timer))
        timer -= 1


start_button = Button(root, text="Press to start!", command=start)
start_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

timer_text = StringVar()
timer_text.set("")

timer_label = Label(root, textvariable=timer_text)
timer_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting that when I pressed the button, the timer would appear on the window and count down from 10 seconds and end at zero. This did not happen.

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` while using `tkinter` most of the time. Look at the [`.after`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/11106801) method instead

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` does exactly what it says: it puts the entire app to sleep. It can't update the display when it's sleeping.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley But shouldn't the code then update the display when it's not sleeping?

Comment: Tkinter is single threaded. That means that while your loop is running, can only run the code in your loop. `mainloop` needs to be able to process events. There are many questions and answers about this on this site.

Comment: NONE of the tkinter functions actually does any drawing.  All they do is queue up messages that will processed later, when you get back to the main loop.  The main loop then fetches and dispatches the messages, and those handlers do the actual drawing.  You don't do UI stuff like this in real time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the window to update between the sleeps you can use the `.update()` method:

```
def start():
    timer = 5
    for _ in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        timer_text.set(str(timer))
        root.update()
        timer -= 1
```

Because your app is single-thread, it is going to freeze while running the loop. You can fix that using the `.after()` method:

```
def start():
    timer = 5
    def change_time(time):
        timer_text.set(str(time))
        if time > 1:
            root.after(1000, change_time, time-1)
    change_time(timer)
```

This solution will work only if you click the start button once.

If you don't want to use [`global`](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/global-variables) variables to solve it, you can create a `Timer` widget:

```
class Timer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        start_button = Button(self, text="Press to start!", command=self.start)
        start_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.timer_text = StringVar()
        self.timer_text.set("")

        self.timer_label = Label(self, textvariable=self.timer_text)
        self.timer_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
        
        self.call_time = None
    
    def set_timer(self, timer):
        self.timer_text.set(str(timer))
        if timer > 1:
            self.call_time = root.after(1000, self.set_timer, timer - 1)
        
        
    def start(self):
        if self.call_time:
            self.after_cancel(self.call_time)
            
        self.set_timer(5)
```

And then use it:

```
root = Tk()

root.title("timer")
root.geometry("200x250")

start_text = Label(root, text="Timer test")
start_text.grid(row=1, column=1)
timer = Timer(root)
timer.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: That still puts the UI to sleep for a full second at a time.  The correct plan is to use `root.after` to request a callback one second from now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to do a countdown in tkinter.  Your callbacks should be almost instantaneous; use the APIs to request a callback at some point in the future.

```
timer = 0
def count():
    global timer
    timer -= 1
    timer_text.set(str(timer))
    if timer:
        root.after( 1000, count )

def start():
    global timer
    timer = 5+1
    count()
```

Or, even:

```
def count(timer):
    timer_text.set(str(timer))
    if timer:
        root.after( 1000, lambda: count(timer-1) )

def start():
    count(5)
```

Comment: Minor note: `after( 1000, lambda: count(timer-1) )` can be simplified to `after(1000, count, timer-1)`. The `.after` method takes any number of arguments and they are passed in to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks -- most of tkinter is so primitive, I didn't realize this was an option.